# How to edit a bootstrap template

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a bootstrap template for styling. i am using *sonic* template for styling. I have downloaded the zip file of sonic template.I want to add my text, button and images. How to modify the template.
http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_394_sonic/

Comment: Have you opened the file? I think you can edit it from there

Comment: The link which i have given is the demo only..

Comment: i have only downloaded the zip folder of template ...only css and java script files are there in this folder

Answer (score 3):

the way you downloaded it, unzip it - open folder and use one of many text/code editor and change the things you want to ? is your question correct ?!

Comment: @michaelcorleone I hope it was sarcasm :)

Comment: hope is the only way :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better idea than downloading from a Zip file.

Here’s a link to the site - https://www.scribd.com/document/332827979/Getting-Started-Bootstrap

```
The folks over at MaxCDN provide CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. Just use these Bootstrap CDN links.

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
To enable screen reader support, press shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Z. To learn about keyboard shortcuts, press shortcut Ctrl+slash.
```